# Return sum of multiple values and corresponding category field of max value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data

```
ID  CATEGORY VALUE
x   A        10
x   B        2
x   C        1
y   B        11
y   A        6
z   D        13
z   E        0
```

I would like to group by **ID** and **Category** such that **Value** is summed for a single **ID** and the **Category** returned is that of the corresponding max **Value** within the **ID** group.

The results would look like this.

```
ID  CATEGORY    VALUE
x   A           13
y   B           17
z   D           13
```

Is this possible in SQL?

Thanks

Comment: What if you have *two* maximum values with the same `Id`? E.e. `(x, A, 10)` and `(x, Z, 10)` records?

Comment: Had not considered that. The problem I am looking will not have such scenarios but that is a valid point. Mostly I will have a category with one large value and the other categories will be very small in comparison or zero. If I did have two maximum values, I would return both categories.

Answer (score 1):

Try window function rank:

```
select id, category, value 
  from (
   select id, category, sum(value) over (partition by id) as value,
          rank() over (partition by id order by value desc) as rnk
    from mytable) t
where rnk=1;
```

If you have duplicates with same value it'll show both. (if 'x','B' had value 10):

```
id  cat value
x   A   21
x   B   21
y   B   17
z   D   13
```

Comment: @e.shee If you think this answer is perfect, then you should mark and upvote  this answer.

Comment: I have tried to upvote and mark as resolved but keep receiving errors. Will try again later.

Comment: @e.shee You probably don't have enough reputation to upvote, but you should be able to mark as answered

Comment: Again, have tried but am receiving message: "An error has occured - please retry your request".

Comment: @e.shee Maybe logout-login?